# Reformulate this PDE in different notation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab, finance

I would like to rewrite this general PDE
\begin{equation}
\alpha\partial_tu+\beta\partial_xu+\gamma\partial_{xx}u+\delta u=\varepsilon
\end{equation}
in this form
$$c\left(x,t,u,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=x^{-m}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[x^m f\left(x,t,u,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)\right]+s\left(x,t,u,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) $$
where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \varepsilon $ are functions in $x$ or simple coefficients.

For example setting $\alpha=1, \beta=rx, \gamma=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x^2, \delta=-r,\varepsilon=0$ one gets the Black-Scholes equation, while with different settings it is possible to price different financial securities.

My goal is to restate the starting equation to solve it with matlab which adopts the second form.

I read online some guides and tried to understand the examples but how I can switch from one notation to the other is still opaque.

I suppose $s$ to be linked with $\beta$ as there is only the first derivative wrt $x$, $c$ with $\alpha$ as the first derivative wrt $t$ happears.

I can't get exactly how to match each coefficent function in the two formulations and in particular what $m$ and $f$ represent.

Any help or reference will be really appreciate.

Comment: Are you planning on using MATLAB's 'pdepe'?

Comment: Yes, as the PDE is parabolic and 'pdepe' is supposed to solve it. But if there is an easier way I will be more than happy to consider it.

Comment: There should be an extra differential outside the bracketed statement, then. It should be edited now.

Comment: I edited as you were right. Do you have some hint @Brandon?

Comment: In general, it will depend upon the PDE you choose to study.  For Black-Scholes, and assuming $r$ is nonzero, take $c=\frac{1}{r}$, $m=0$, $f=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2r}x^2\partial_x u$, and $s=u$. The best reference I have is http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html?refresh=true, which you may have already looked at.